# I tried to do the following and it didn't work with LWC and Apex, does anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Apex:

```
public with sharing class test2Ctrl {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Contact getcontactCtrl(String recordId) {
        return [
            SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email
            FROM Contact
            WHERE Id =: recordId
        ];
    }
}
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from "lwc";
import getAccountList from "@salesforce/apex/test2Ctrl.getAccountList";

export default class Test2 extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getAccountList, { recordId: '$recordId' }) accounts;
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Account List From Apex" icon-name="custom:custom63">
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <template if:true={accounts.data}>
                    <template for:each={accounts.data} for:item="acc">
                        <p key={acc.Id}>{acc.Name}</p>
                    </template>
                </template>
                <template if:true={accounts.error}>
                    {accounts.error}
                </template>
            </div>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

it shows me a message of:
[object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Apex is looking for a single contact, but your LWC is looking for a list of accounts. You can do something like this in your LWC. You don't need Apex if the page has a recordId. You can use getRecord instead.

```
// Imports
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
// UI imports
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
// Schema imports (import others that you need
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Name';

const FIELDS = [NAME];

export default class WireGetValue extends LightningElement {
    // Public properties
    @api recordId;

    // Wire functions
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', FIELDS })
    contact;

    get name() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, NAME_FIELD);
    }
}

<template>
    <lightning-card title="Contact" icon-name="standard:contact">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template if:true={contact.data}>
                    <p>{name}</p>
                </template>
            </template>
            <template if:true={contact.error}>
                {contact.error}
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Now it doesn't show me anything it just tells me [object Object]

Comment: please stop naming your questions similar to "I tried to do the following and it didn't work with LWC and Apex, does anyone know how to fix it?" instead, give a title representative of the issue or error you are encountering 